# Subquery returned more than 1 value. How to fix it?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query to show data that i want. but it gives me error [Err] 21000 - [SQL Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

data : MCRX-MX023-LF-KGX, but when I enter the other data there is no error

this is Sql server 2008

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SupplierID,
            CurrencyAP AS Currency,
            (
                SELECT
                    UnitPrice
                FROM
                    Ms_PartPriceSupplier
                WHERE
                    SupplierID = x.SupplierID
                AND PartID = x.PartID
                AND LastUpdateDate = x.Tgl
            ) AS Price,
            PartID,
            (
                SELECT
                    PartnerName
                FROM
                    Ms_Partner
                WHERE
                    PartnerID = x.SupplierID
            ) SupplierName
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    PartID,
                    SupplierID,
                    CurrencyAP,
                    MAX (LastUpdateDate) AS Tgl
                FROM
                    Ms_PartPriceSupplier
                WHERE
                    PartID = 'MCRX-MX023-LF-KGX'
                GROUP BY
                    PartID,
                    SupplierID,
                    CurrencyAP
            ) x
    ) y
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        PartnerID AS SupplierID,
        '' AS Currency,
        0 AS Price,
        '' AS PartID,
        PartnerName AS SupplierName
    FROM
        Ms_Partner
    WHERE
        PartnerID NOT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                SupplierID
            FROM
                Ms_PartPriceSupplier
            WHERE
                PartID = 'MCRX-MX023-LF-KGX'
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELECT subqueries for the `Price` and/or `SupplierName` columns in your query return multiple values. They should return only a single value (per row).

You can either provide a TOP (1) in those subqueries or adjust the conditions in their WHERE/HAVING clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your subqueries returns more than 1 value

```
            SELECT
                UnitPrice
            FROM
                Ms_PartPriceSupplier
            WHERE
                SupplierID = x.SupplierID
            AND PartID = x.PartID
            AND LastUpdateDate = x.Tgl

            SELECT
                PartnerName
            FROM
                Ms_Partner
            WHERE
                PartnerID = x.SupplierID
```

Add `TOP (1)` or some aggregation function like `MIN`, `MAX` in appliance with your requirements, for instance:

```
        SELECT TOP (1)
            UnitPrice
        FROM
            Ms_PartPriceSupplier
        WHERE
            SupplierID = x.SupplierID
        AND PartID = x.PartID
        AND LastUpdateDate = x.Tgl

        SELECT TOP (1)
            PartnerName
        FROM
            Ms_Partner
        WHERE
            PartnerID = x.SupplierID
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. When you use a subquery in place of not a table but a value, then you must ensure only one value is returned, else you will get this error message.

Further investigation of your query reveals that you... are doing it wrong. For example,

```
    (
        SELECT
            PartnerName
        FROM
            Ms_Partner
        WHERE
            PartnerID = x.SupplierID
    ) SupplierName
```

It seems here that you want to get the name that is associated with each SupplierID. You should not do subqueries in the `SELECT` section this way. Remember: `FROM` gets evaluated first, then `WHERE`, then `SELECT`. What you actually instructed the database here is to try to return a SINGLE value as SupplierName: this will only work if your query only has one SupplierID.

You need to start thinking with joins. Here is how you should write your query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SupplierID,
            CurrencyAP AS Currency,
            Ms_PartPriceSupplier.UnitPrice AS Price,
            PartID,
            Ms_Partner.PartnerName as SupplierName
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    PartID,
                    SupplierID,
                    CurrencyAP,
                    MAX (LastUpdateDate) AS Tgl
                FROM
                    Ms_PartPriceSupplier
                WHERE
                    PartID = 'MCRX-MX023-LF-KGX'
                GROUP BY
                    PartID,
                    SupplierID,
                    CurrencyAP
            ) x
            inner join Ms_Partner on PartnerID = x.SupplierID
            inner join Ms_PartPriceSupplier on SupplierID = x.SupplierID AND PartID = x.PartID AND LastUpdateDate = x.Tgl
    ) y
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        PartnerID AS SupplierID,
        '' AS Currency,
        0 AS Price,
        '' AS PartID,
        PartnerName AS SupplierName
    FROM
        Ms_Partner
    WHERE
        PartnerID NOT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                SupplierID
            FROM
                Ms_PartPriceSupplier
            WHERE
                PartID = 'MCRX-MX023-LF-KGX'
        )
```